# Redistributing batch result in multi-threaded Tensorflow

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I'm enqueqing multiple inputs to data a TF.FIFOqueue using

```
q = tf.FIFOQueue(...)
```

The data is generated by threads, each loading a data point using q.enqueue, and waiting for evaluation. Once a batch is ready, I get the output using

```
batch = q.dequeue_many(batch_size)
```

and process the data using some NN.
Now, here's my question:
How can I redistribute the results to each thread, so that each thread will get the prediction for its data point? In other words, how do I know which thread placed entry #1, in order to feed it with output #1?

Alternatively, should I approach the problem differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can enqueue/dequeue tuples of tensors onto/from tf queues. One simple way would be to enqueue a pair `(thread_id, data_point)` instead of just `data_point`. `thread_id` can be a constant integer or string tensor, for example.